# Doctrine nullable one-to-one relationship still wants to create unique index

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a `Person` entity which has two relations (`hometown` and `current`) to `Location` table. Both of these fields can be null, otherwise they must exist in the `Location` table:

```
class Person {
.....
/**
 * @var Location
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Location")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="hometown_id", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=true)
 **/
protected $hometown;

/**
 * @var Location
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Location")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="current_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 **/     
 protected $current;
....
}
```

Now, I want to update my db schema, based on `doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` output, but it creates problems:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D6494341EE7D ON person (hometown_id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D649B8998A57 ON person (current_id);
```

I cannot define these indexes as there are more than one null row in the table.

Would you please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `OneToOne` relationship is unique as it would mean that only one `person` could be assigned to one `location` and one `location` to one `person`.

In your scenario you would want one `person` to have multiple locations and one `location` could have multiple `person`(s). This would be a `ManyToMany` relationship.

In Doctrine when you use a `ManyToMany` you will specify a `JoinTable` that Doctrine will manage (You don't have to create an entity for a `JoinTable`). The `JoinTable` breaks down the `ManyToMany` to something like a `OneToMany` such as one `person` to many `location`(s) as shown in example below. The `JoinTable` will store the values you want when they apply.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Location")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="hometown_location",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="location_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 **/
protected $hometown;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Location")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="current_location",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="location_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 **/
protected $current;

public function __construct() {
    $this->hometown = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->hometown = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

If there is no `location` to assign to `hometown` or `current` that is fine, no space is taken up.
When you do have a `location` to assign to either `hometown` or `current` it will have to be a valid `location` from the `location` table.

Comment: Hi @hcoat, thanks for your reply. In my scenario, a person has only one hometown and one current location OR it doesn't have any. So, in my case `Person <--> Location` should be `1 <--> 0..1` for both relations. Because of that I put `OneToOne` relation with `nullable=true`.

Comment: Currently, Location table doesn't have any link to any table since the other tables like Person fetch their required information using the `location_id` and I don't want to add more fields to it. While if I use ManyToOne, it needs me to do so :( Is there any way to achieve my goal?

Comment: As you may notice, I've implemented this idea without doctrine, and now I am moving to this framework. I think the best database structure for my case is as I mentioned. But if I want to implement it by Doctrine, I need to change that in a kinda inefficient way. before it only needed to join 2 tables and now I have to join 3.

Comment: My point is that why should a nullable one-to-one relation need to create a unique index? `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D6494341EE7D ON person (hometown_id);`

Comment: Doctrine seems to always forces unique in a unidirectional 1:1. However a `ManyToOne` will not, but I am not sure why you are saying you would have to add more fields if you used it? It appear the to me that you should be able to swap `OneToOne` in your code for `ManyToOne`.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I was doing a goofy mistake and putting OneToMany in `Person` entity! Now I changed applied and it worked. I thought 0..1 means `Many' and It should be `One` `Person' to `Many` `Locations` but it's vice-verse. Thanks

Comment: And this means that 1:1 relation in doctrine doesn't work with multiple NULL values.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for FOREIGN KEY

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

```
ALTER TABLE `Person` ADD INDEX ( `hometown_id` ) ;
ALTER TABLE `Person` ADD FOREIGN KEY ( `hometown_id` ) REFERENCES `Location` ( `id` )
ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT ;

ALTER TABLE `Person` ADD INDEX ( `current_id` ) ;
ALTER TABLE `Person` ADD FOREIGN KEY ( `current_id` ) REFERENCES `Location` ( `id` )
ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT ;
```

Comment: "Unique" would mean that you prohibit two people to live in the same city

Comment: thank you for the reply. The SQL code is generated by the Doctrine2 Tool and the problem resides in the definition of the entities in PHP not MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Late reply only because it shows in the searches:

What you describe is not a OneToOne association. It becomes clear when we imagine a person whose current location is his/her hometown.
In that case both properties of `Person` will have the same `id`.
OneToOne associations normally share the same primary key, hence Doctrine trying to create unique indexes.

This is a ManyToOne association and can be declared as:

```
class Person {
.....
/**
 * @var Location|null
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Location")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="hometown_id", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=true)
 **/
protected $hometown;

/**
 * @var Location|null
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Location")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="current_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 **/     
 protected $current;
....
}
```

Note: Annotations NOT tested.